# Is Roslyn ready for C# 10?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-10.0

Is Roslyn ready for C# 10?

Here is my old code:

```
syntaxTrees.AddRange( filesToCompile.ConvertAll( filename => Parse( File.ReadAllText( filename ), filename, CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion( LanguageVersion.CSharp9 ) ) ) );
```

The part that seems more relevant:

```
CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion( LanguageVersion.CSharp9 )
```

It doesn't seem that the language version has a `CSharp10` enum yet?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022

Comment: I was able to compile my solution with .NET 6 but my program also uses in-memory compilation for some things.  This is working but not if I use c#10 language features ( e.g. file-scoped namespaces - the first thing I tried ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp) onwards to use C# 10. The first non-preview version is 4.0.1.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp --version 4.0.1
```

Then you can use `LanguageVersion.CSharp10`

Comment: This worked for me.  Do you know when it comes out of preview?  I might be just a little early with 2022 release party :)

Comment: The version 4.0.1 has been published a few hours ago https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

[LanguageVersion.CSharp10](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/54359) was added in June and is available currently in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` version  4.0.0 preview nuget builds, the latest being [Version 4.0.0-6.final](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/4.0.0-6.final).